# Android Change Package name and not working

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

My problem is i was have one project name is "com.old.name" and i change that 
"com.new.name" before it's was work every thing with not problem but now when i'm try to emulate that showing that error

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.old.name/com.new.name.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.old.name/com.new.name.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

It's must be work first just only com.new.name.MainActivity but does not work like this. I don't understand why . I clear the project and change the name in androidmanifest.xml but still have same problem.

Part of my manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lucky.draw"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

When i'm searching com.old.name i don't find any variable about that now i don't know where i need to change.

I'm using android studio

Comment: Did you change the name in the build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes there connect with androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you need to use the function of the Refactor such as this:

[image]

if you get some tips, you need to care about the reference and usage to make sure that all the related code should be change based on the new package name. such as this:
[image]

Comment: According to your log, there are still something with old package name:
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.old.name/com.new.name.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.old.name/com.new.name.MainActivity} does not exist.

Comment: Could you snapshot your Project Structure View of your project?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the build of your project,try to  check the "Deploy application" checkbox in the Run/Debug Configuration screen.